# Observable.forkJoin rxJs requests within another request

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want some way to send two requests to my server to get list of Objects (DocumentComponent) and in this DocumentComponent I have a List of Object DocumentContents

so I need that after each time I get one object DocumentComponent I get also its DocumentContents

```
this.gridService.getAllDocumentComponentByTemplate(1)
            .subscribe(data => {
                    this.documentComponents = data;
                    console.log(this.documentComponents);
                    for (var component of this.documentComponents) {
                           this.getAllDocumentContents(component.id);
                    }
                },
                error => alert('Erreur ' + error),
                () => {
                    console.log("finished  ");
                }
            );
```

but this method is not working in parallel 
I get just the last List of DocumentContent for latest DocumentComponent

so how to use Observable.forkJoin or if there are another way to do that thank you

```
 Observable.forkJoin(
            this.gridService.getAllDocumentComponentByTemplate(1),
            this.gridService.getAllDocumentContentByDocumentComponent(**id**)
        ).subscribe(data => {
            this.documentComponents = data[0];
            this.documentContents = data[1];
        },
            err => console.error(err)
    );
```

I tried that but I get the latest list of DocumentContents because I put as id in the second method getAllDocumentContentByDocumentComponent as a static value I need to make it variable

thank you for your time

```
getAllDocumentContentByDocumentComponent(idDocumentComponent:number) {
        return this._http.get('http://localhost:8080/template/getAllDocumentContentByDocumentComponent/' + idDocumentComponent)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
    getAllDocumentComponentByTemplate(idDocument:number) {
        return this._http.get('http://localhost:8080/template/getAllDocumentComponentByTemplate/' + idDocument)
            .map(res => res.json());
    }
```

Comment: What is exactly the `id` and to get it from the previous request? Thanks!

Comment: the id is the foreign id of DocumentContent of DocumentComponent

from this id i have access to all DocumentContent of the current DocumentComponent

Comment: Okay. `getAllDocumentComponentByTemplate` returns a list of `DocumentComponent`? or a single one?

Comment: yeesss exactly it return a list I will update My question

Answer (score 1):

I would try something like that:

```
this.gridService.getAllDocumentComponentByTemplate(1)
    .flatMap(documentComponents => {
      let contentObservables =  documentComponents.map(documentComponent => {
        return this.gridService.getAllDocumentContentByDocumentComponent(
          documentComponent.id);
      });

      return Observable.forkJoin([
        Observable.of(documentComponents),
        ...contentObservables
      ]);
    })
```

First get the document components, build the observables to get contents for each component and then execute all in parallel using `forkJoin`.

Note the use of `Observable.of` to be able to get the result of the initial request.